# iOS-Swift: Possible ways to design horizontal paging with tableview inside each page?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, horizontal-scrolling

Whats is the best way to design (and also possible ways) horizontal paging with tableview inside each page? Slide in Slide out animation would be perfect. Basically something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11262047/uitableviewcontroller-inside-uiscrollview-with-horizontal-paging) but using newer UI views like collectionview

**Update**: What I am trying to do it just break up a table with lets say 12 items into three pages with 4 items each.

So the question is UIPageViewController VS UIScrollView VS UICollectionView

Comment: Hi T_C, you should know by now that "what is the best X" questions are off-topic at Stack Overflow, as they're primarily opinion-based.

Comment: @TylerH yes, changed it to possible :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a `UIPageViewController`. It's built-in and is perfect for horizontal scrolling (sliding) between view controllers.

Comment: I was going to suggest that but you beat me to it. A page view controller is perfect for this. You'd use a page view controller to manage a series of `UITableViewController`s, or regular view controllers that contain table views.

Comment: Wouldnt UIPageViewController mean, i need a different view controller in each page. I just updated my question, I am trying to break up my tableview with 12 cells into 3 pages with 4 cells each

Comment: @DuncanC Can I just have UITableView inside each of them ?

Comment: @T_C You could use a collection view with 3 columns of four rows, instead of 3 table views, sure. But I'm not changing my answer. I don't see any disadvantage to a UIPageViewController and three table views because, if you can only see one column at a time, I don't see any sense in which this is all "one" table view. You can reuse the same UITableViewController class for all three tables.

Comment: @matt awesome, thanks, but what is advantage of using one over the other   ?

Comment: @T_C, no, the pages in a `UIPageViewController` need to be view controllers, not views. If all you want is a table view in each one then use a `UITableViewController` for each page.

Comment: @T_C I don't know what "advantage" even means. Programmers try stuff! Try different ways of doing it and see what you think.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider using a UIPageView then build your collection views on each page. Here's an example cocoapod that sounds like what you are describing:

https://github.com/lxian/LXPageViewWithButtonsViewController

Comment: Wouldnt UIPageViewController mean, i need a different view controller in each page. I just updated my question, I am trying to break up my tableview with 12 cells into 3 pages with 4 cells each